# How to efficiently implement a newsletter system to prevent duplicate e-mails?

Tags: php, mysql, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

We run an e-commerce site with approximately 500,000 active customers. We regularly send newsletters via an external mail service (https://www.campaignmonitor.com/) however as the company grows and we get more customers, our newsletter costs increase.
I recently came across Amazon SES which is perfect for us as they are cheap and since we are already using AWS for our servers, it makes things a little easier to maintain. I know there's cheaper alternatives, but I would prefer to stick to Amazon SES.

Let's say I create a newsletter in my system that sends an e-mail to everyone that's having a birthday today. It just so happens that 400,000 people have a birthday today, so 400,000 e-mails get sent.
The next day, the remaining 100,000 people have birthdays as well as 100,000 more people that already received the birthday e-mail yesterday but changed their birth date to this day because they entered it incorrectly when they signed up. The system now sees 200,000 e-mails to send, but should know to only send to 100,000 of them because 100,000 already received the e-mail for the time period (365 days).

The problem I'm having is regarding database and script efficiency.

On the first day, I store the e-mail addresses of 400,000 people in a table called "sent".
On the second day, I retrieve the list of all e-mail addresses to send to. I then have the following options:

- Query the "sent" table 200,000 times to see which e-mail addresses to send to - Extremely inefficient, plus unnecessary load on the server that is running the site itself.
- Retrieve the entire "sent" table, store into an array and filter accordingly - Fast (just 1 DB query), but requires a lot of RAM. This is currently how I do things, but obviously I receive PHP memory exhausted errors, so it's no longer viable, especially as the site grows.
- Sort the 200,000 e-mail addresses alphabetically and query the "sent" table in batches, such as all of the A e-mail addresses, all of the B e-mail addresses, and so on. - Fast and should use less RAM depending on the batch conditions, but what if all 200,000 e-mail addresses begin with the letter S?
- Something else?!

I realize that these are very extreme examples that will never happen in a real environment, but I would prefer to (re)implement this correctly now and not have to revisit it again in the future.

If Amazon SES has this functionality built in, I would love to know where I can find it! I've searched their docs but I can't see it.

Does anyone have any experience in this field, or have any suggestions? I've been racking my brain for days trying to come up with a good solution, but I just can't come up with anything.

HELP! :)

---

EDIT: I'm using MySQL. I've looked into No-SQL but don't feel it's necessary.

EDIT: The birthday thing is just an example of a newsletter. It should be a completely generic system that does not rely on any predefined notions of what the data contains.

EDIT: The server already implements good e-mail practices such as SPF, DKIM, and so forth.

EDIT: I decided to refactor things and create my own file and/or memory based indexer which solves the problem, to a degree. Case closed, at least for now.

Comment: SQL Relational Database support these things called 'set based operations'. If you happen to have both (or rather, all relevant) sets available in the database this makes things super easy and there is no need to run N queries or pull N records to perform needless client-side work. (Thus it is merely a matter of determining what is stored and how it relates.)

Comment: plus, if people change their bdays, they should expect things to be wonky in terms of automatic actions. and if you expect your userbase to be 25% "dummies", then perhaps they shouldn't be on the net in the first place.

Comment: There is a reason campainmonitor is a viable business - dont underestimate the engineering involved and the possible consequences of cocking this up

Comment: But a simple approach with a subquery; `SELECT email FROM users WHERE birthday = today AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM sent)`

Comment: doing this yourself, incorrectly, will get you on every spam blacklist faster than you can say *Cthulhu fhtagn*

Comment: @Dagon except if you know what you are doing, SPF, DKIM, Ip reputation, bounch rate etc etc. But SES can handle this I think

Comment: *It should be a completely generic system that does not rely on any predefined notions of what the data contains.* coding for every possible situation is basically impossible.

Comment: Your idea to batch/sort the list alphabetically (point 3) should be replaced with a  `LIMIT` statement and get the appropriate number of records for your memory constraints.

Comment: no real need for limit, just loop the returned data from the db, don't need to store it

Comment: Elastic search would be a nice start for things like this

Comment: @Dagon Obviously someone has never used SharePoint *:rolls eyes:*

Answer (score 2):

You can either write your own system or leverage an existing tool.  On google Sendy https://sendy.co/  comes as the first result for 'php mysql SES newsletter' which seems right up your alley based on the tags you sent.  There are 1000's of other PHP/Mysql based newsletter programs that might work for you.  That one looked pretty neat.

As far as being concerned about server load.  I would spin up a "small" instance in AWS and use that just for your email system.   That way you don't have to worry about long running processes or timeouts causing your problems on your production website.  200,000 or 500,000 records really isn't that many.  I bet you spend more time waiting for Amazon SES to respond than actually waiting on queries to return or parse.